# How to install multiple packages with winget?

Tags: windows, winget

How to install multiple packages with winget  ?

Is this the only way ? https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/219
I mean is there any ability out of the box ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such built-in functionality. You could use the script [provided by Danstis](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/219#issuecomment-977475839) in that GitHub link you posted, but depending on your exact use case (creating a PS script for various users / machines, running it remotely, etc), it might be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now there is no way to install multiple packages with a single command - with the exception of `winget import`. If you know the Package Identifier and the source details, it is possible to create a JSON file that can be used to install a set of packages. However, this still involves the additional step of creating the JSON file